# How to exclude a matching pattern but also include specific values matching the pattern in SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, database

A SQL query fetches many numbers but excludes the numbers starting with digit 4:

```
Select Var 
from TABLE 
Where Var NOT LIKE '4%'
```

Now I need to include/fetch 3 specific values(in the same query) which also start with 4.

I modified the above query but this doesn't work:

```
Select Var from Table
where Var NOT LIKE '4%' AND
      ( Var = '40030' OR Var = '40100' OR Var = '40130' )
```

Comment: Do you want to include something like `30000` ?

Comment: UNION ALL of these 2 queries is the most suitable solution. *Will below statement work* No. Your conditions are alternatives, hence you need OR, not AND, between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking for the UNION of  `Var NOT LIKE '4%'` and `Var in ('40030', '40100', '40130')`.  So use an OR condition to accomplish that:

```
Where (Var in ('40030', '40100', '40130')) or
            ( Var NOT LIKE '4%')
```